# Nativescript + Vue - Errores de ejecucion

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

Estoy desarrollando una App con NativeScript + Vue.js y estoy compilando con el Smart phone conectado al PC. El problema que tengo es que cuando tengo un error en alguna parte de la Aplicacion, toda la aplicacion deja de funcionar. Para ser mas exacto ejecuta las llamadas al Backend pero sucede que el template pierde conexion con el resto de la aplicacion.
Por ejemplo carga un array desde el Backend, pero no lo muestra en el template. Tienen idea que podria ser?

Comment: ¿Tienes algún código al respecto?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con tu pregunta solo se pueden suponer cosas, y en el sitio tratamos de no suponer nada.. muestra algo que pueda ayudarnos a saber que pasa...